# Ionic: How to upload file from Google Drive using Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-drive-api, storage-access-framework

I am developing a hybrid application using Ionic Framework for Android and iOS platforms. Currently I am stuck at a stage where I want the users to add an attachment to their post. For adding particular type of attachments I am using:

1. cordova-plugin-camera: for photos and videos
2. cordova-filechooser(https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser): for documents and files

**Now, I want the user to add files(images, videos, documents etc.) from their Google Drive Account using Storage Access Framework. Currently, from my FileChooser plugin I can only see the files that are on my device. How can I achieve this?**

I am attaching an image with this post so as to make it more clear.

[image]

Comment: `from my FileChooser plugin`. But does that use SAF to begin with?

Comment: On github link for FileChooser plugin, you will be able to see an image that shows "Google Drive" listed in the UI along with other options. But there is no code in the repository that links it to Google Drive. Therefore, I need a solution by which I can list Google Drive in SAF for my application.

Comment: Yoh did not answer my question.

Comment: I think it isn't using SAF.

Comment: Why that file chooser plugin where you can use ACTION_OPEN__DOCUMENT ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your comment as I am new to ionic and cordova? Please explain me how can I achieve this .

Comment: No i cannot. I know nothing of those environments. Google for it.

Comment: Why isn't anybody answering this question?